# Can a ger tzedek be a sofer?

Tags: safrus

I just heard from somebody that there is a machlokes whether a ger tzedek can be a sofer or not. What are the sources (if any)? If it is, then would that make it impossible to earn money as one if you're a ger?

Comment: see Pri Megadim, Eshel Avraham 39:9 - that's the tip of the iceberg for views of the achronim...

Comment: I don't get it, Sefer Ovadia in Trei asar in the Tenach was writen by a Ger Tzedek?

Comment: Smaya and Avtalyon were on the Sanhedrin and wer both gerei tzedek. Why should a sofer not be a ger tzededk?

Comment: @sabbahillel The source (and reason) barring a convert from being a scribe [for a Torah] is from mas. Soferim ([ch. 14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22498&st=&pgnum=106&hilite=), cf. the sources in n. 66). The issue then arose if tefilin should be included or not and whether or not all kinds of converts are included as well.

Comment: @Oliver This should be included in the question, rather than a comment. The details should be part of the question.

Comment: @sabbahillel I didn't ask the question :)

Comment: @ol Curious if anyone suggests that that text arose due to a merging of a vav and yud rendering a reish, since contextually that would make a lot more sense, especially considering the concluding *klal*.